# Remove image elements from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, image

I have a string that contains HTML image elements that is stored in a var.

I want to remove the image elements from the string.

I have tried: `var content = content.replace(/<img.+>/,"");`

and: `var content = content.find("img").remove();` but had no luck.

Can anyone help me out at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var content = content.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
```

`[^>]*` means any number of characters other than `>`. If you use `.+` instead, if there are multiple tags the replace operation removes them all at once, including any content between them. Operations are greedy by default, meaning they use the largest possible valid match.

`/g` at the end means replace all occurrences (by default, it only removes the first occurrence).

Comment: **Note:** Will not work if the `img` is like this: `<img src="blah.png" title=">:(" />`. A better way to do it is: `var content = $(content).find("img").remove().html();`

Comment: @Derek, it needs an `end()` function: `var content = $(content).find("img").remove().end().html();`, as per @Scott Evernden's answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('<p>').html(content).find('img').remove().end().html()
```

Comment: $('.selector').find('img').remove(); works as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Please do not use regex to parse html

Answer (score 8):

## The following Regex should do the trick:

```
var content = content.replace(/<img[^>"']*((("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))[^"'>]*)*>/g,"");
```

It first matches the `<img`. Then `[^>"']*` matches any character except for `>`, `"` and  `'` any number of times. Then `(("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))` matches two `"` with any character in between (except `"` itself, which is this part `[^"]*`) or the same thing, but with two `'` characters.

> An example of this would be `"asf<>!('"` or `'akl>"<?'`.

This is again followed by any character except for `>`, `"` and  `'` any number of times. The Regex concludes when it finds a `>` outside a set of single or double quotes.

This would then account for having `>` characters inside attribute strings, as pointed out by [@Derek 朕會功夫](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283863/derek) and would therefore match and remove all four image tags in the following test scenario:

```
<img src="blah.png" title=">:(" alt=">:)" /> Some text between <img src="blah.png" title="<img" /> More text between <img /><img src='asdf>' title="sf>">
```

This is of course inspired by [@Matt Coughlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306809/matt-coughlin)'s answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, it will remove all HTML tags!

```
var content = $("<p>"+content+"</p>").text();
```

Comment: Thanks - but I need to retain all the other HTML tags - just not img ones

Answer (score 4):

I'm in IE right now...this worked great, but my tags come out in upper case (after using innerHTML, i think) ... so I added "i" to make it case insensitive. Now Chrome and IE are happy.

```
var content = content.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?:

```
var content = content.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '')
```

Comment: It needs a //g or it only removes one img tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the text as a DOM element, then use jQuery to find all images and remove them. I generally try to treat XML (html in this case) as XML and not try to parse through the strings.

```
var element = $('<p>My paragraph has images like this <img src="foo"/> and this <img src="bar"/></p>');

element.find('img').remove();

newText = element.html();

console.log(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without regex or libraries (read jQuery), you could use DOMParser to parse your string, then use plain JS to do any manipulations and re-serialize to get back your string.